# how to make correct test

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, mockk

I try to make test of this with mockk but I can't make it because of Coroutine.
notesUseCases.getAllNotesUseCase.invoke() returns `Flow<List<Note>>`, and note is something like this `Note(1, "Note 1", "Content 1", false)`.

```
@HiltViewModel
class NotesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val notesUseCases: NotesUseCases
): ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(NotesState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        getNotes()
    }
    private fun getNotes() {
        notesUseCases.getAllNotesUseCase.invoke().onEach { notes ->
            _state.value = state.value.copy(
                allNotes = notes,
                notes = notes.filter { !it.isDeleted }
            )
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

this is my test which I try to run

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class NotesViewModelTest {
    private val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

    private lateinit var viewModel: NotesViewModel
    private val notesUseCases: NotesUseCases = mockk()
    private val remoteUseCases: RemoteUseCases = mockk()


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        coEvery { notesUseCases.getAllNotesUseCase.invoke() } returns flow {
            emit(listOf(
                Note(1, "Note 1", "Content 1", false),
                Note(2, "Note 2", "Content 2", false)
            ))
        }
        coEvery { remoteUseCases.checkIsSynchronize.execute() } returns Resource.Success(true)

        viewModel = NotesViewModel(
            notesUseCases,
            remoteUseCases
        )

        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    @Test
    fun takeNotes_TakeFromMockkTwoNotes() = runBlocking {
        assertThat(viewModel.state.value.allNotes.size).isEqualTo(2)
    }
}
```

I try make test of viewModel which taking data from room db via flow data.

Comment: Set the main dispatcher before creating the ViewModel